# Is it bad to use Singletons for immutable no-argument classes?

Tags: java, oop, singleton, immutability, single-instance

I am working on a small Java Project right now, and while doing so there where multiple classes created which represent some kind of Constant behaviour for example use as default return value for other methods.

Now what all these have in common is, that they are completely immutable and that they only have a no argument constructor. This means that creating multiple instances of that class will always result in identical objects.

Is it better to just create a new instance everytime these classes are used or is this a acceptable case to use the singelton pattern?

Comment: Without seeing the classes, this sounds reasonable as there's no point in having multiple instances of equivalent objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider pros and cons of singleton assuming you have a small project and immutable classes that are used as default return values.

**Pros** of singleton in this case:

- **Application constructs one object instead of many**;
  Keep in mind that generally constructing a new object is a cheap operation in Java.
  If your objects do not live long, GC will collect them without significant impact on the performance of your app. This is applicable if you don't have to create thousands of such objects per second.

**Cons**:

- **More code to read and write**;
  While writing `getInstance()` methods might not look like a big deal, other people (potentially) working with you will spend some time exploring what `getInstance()` really does when fixing bugs or just undertanding some business logic. I've seen a number of surprising `getInstance()` methods though they had a conventional name.
- **Potential concurrency issues**;
  Even if your project is small you may want to utilize multiple threads. In this case you have to write `getInstance()` as a synchronized method, introduce [double-checked locking](http://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Epugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html), use enums or something else.
  Even if you are aware of this peculiarity, it is not guaranteed that other developers won't make a mistake.

So there is no single right answer I think, it depends on how you see the evolution of your project in future.

Answer (score 1):

Even in a small project, I'd strive to adhere to the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), i.e. a class does not instantiate its own dependencies, but declares them, usually in a constructor. That way, each class can be developed and tested in isolation, while being tied together with everything else using either a framework like Spring or Guice or [manual dependency injection](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/12/dependency-injection-manual-way.html). With a setup like that, you will likely have only one instance of the class in question, but you won't need to implement a classic singleton pattern.

Creating a small project is about making the right tradeoffs: you don't want to over-engineer, but you also don't want to write code that is unextendable and unmaintainable. So no, there is almost never a valid excuse to use the singleton pattern (with the classloader guarding the singleton).

Comment: Most of these Singletons I am creating dont even have dependencies. They just implement some Interfaces with default "do nothing" or "accept everything" behaviours.

Answer (score 0):

Under your circumstances, the use of the Singleton pattern makes sense. For a simple application, you can use a static method to return the instance. If you are working in an environment that provides inversion of control, such as Spring, the IOC framework will handle singletons for you.

Answer (score 0):

In case when exposing methods which modify the state of the immutable class, you must always return a new instance of this class.